SwiftUI ChatView keep scroll position when load more
I am building a ChatView using SwiftUI but I got stuck.

First load -> Load 20 items -> Scroll to bottom: OK
User scroll to top -> Load more 20 items -> Scroll position is not work as common chat view behaviour

    import SwiftUI
    import Combine

    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var isLoading: Bool = false
        @State private var message: String = ""
        @State var messages = [
            "blah blah blah1",
            "this is a beautiful message2",
            "this is a random message to my future self3",
            "blah blah blah4",
            "this is a beautiful message5",
            "this is a random message to my future self6",
            "blah blah blah7",
            "this is a beautiful message8",
            "this is a random message to my future self9",
            "blah blah blah10",
            "this is a beautiful message11",
            "this is a random message to my future self12",
            "blah blah blah13",
            "this is a beautiful message14",
            "this is a random message to my future self15",
            "blah blah blah16",
            "this is a beautiful message17",
            "this is a random message to my future self18"
        ]
        
        func loadMoreMessages() {
            if isLoading {
                return
            }
            
            isLoading = true
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--0", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--1", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--2", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--3", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--4", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--5", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--6", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--7", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--8", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--9", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--10", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--11", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--12", at: 0)
                messages.insert("\(Date().currentTimeMillis())--13", at: 0)
                
                isLoading = false
            }
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        ScrollViewReader { scrollViewReader in
                            LazyVStack {
                                Text(isLoading ? "Loading" : "Done")
                                    .onAppear() {
                                        loadMoreMessages()
                                    }
                                
                                ForEach(messages, id: \.self) { message in
                                    MessageRow(message: message)
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                        .padding(.vertical)
                                        .id(message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color.black)
                    // text and send button
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Send a message", text: $message)
                            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        Button {
                            messages.append(message)
                            print("message appended")
                        } label: {
                            Text("Send")
                        }
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.black)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .onAppear {
                    isLoading = true
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(messages.last, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        isLoading = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct MessageRow: View {
        let message: String
        let possibleColors: [UIColor] = [
            .blue,
            .yellow,
            .red,
            .green,
            .purple,
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.1176470588, green: 0.8117647059, blue: 0.737254902, alpha: 1),
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.5254901961, blue: 0.137254902, alpha: 1),
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.5725490196, green: 0.5725490196, blue: 0.5725490196, alpha: 1),
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.8784313725, green: 0.4862745098, blue: 0.9294117647, alpha: 1),
        ]

        let possibleUserList = [
            "saldtw",
            "rleaez35799",
            "BigRacks225",
            "kjohnson31221",
            "rsterling23918",
            "spreadbet",
            "jjunior91358",
            "hsolo31549",
        ]

        private func generateRandomUser() -> String {
            let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<8)
            return possibleUserList[randomInt]
        }

        private func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {
            let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<9)
            return possibleColors[randomInt]
        }

        var body: some View {
            HStack () {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Jun 12 at 10:14 PM")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                    Text(generateRandomUser() + ": ")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(generateRandomColor()))
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.bold) +
                    Text(message)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }

Note: I don't want to use proxy.scrollTo(last-view-message-id, anchor: .bottom) because after load new messages, scrollview will be jumping (not a good behaviour)
Any help!
